# multilevel inheritance in c

Tags: c, inheritance

when doing inheritance in pure C like this

```
typedef struct {
    char name[NAMESIZE];
    char sex;
} Person;

typedef struct {
    Person person;
    char job[JOBSIZE];
} Employee;

typedef struct {
    Person person;
    char booktitle[TITLESIZE];
} LiteraryCharacter;
```

I know it is okay to cast a instance of type "LiteraryCharacter" to type "Person", and use it as such. But is it also ok/safe to cast a instance of type "LiteraryCharacter" to type "Employee" and use it as such?

Comment: I don't think the memory will match up. You could do a memcpy between struct's but I am not sure what you will get. And there isn't inheritance in C.

Comment: There is no inheritance in C. That may be a safe cast, but it is not inheritance.

Comment: @ElliottFrisch why must we always snag onto fixed presets of what is and what isn't. For God's sake we're programmers, we built inheritance as an implementation feature in C++ by using C. C doesn't have "syntactic" inheritance but you can use the "inheritance design pattern" for the same purposes.

Comment: Try telling the blokes at `GObject` / `GLib` / `GTK` that there is no inheritance in C -- surprise, the have it. And they implemented `Vala` as a convenient syntactic wrapper over the "inheritance design pattern" they built in C.

Comment: You can have OOP in assembler, before OOP ever was a language feature it was a proéminent design pattern, so popular that skipping all of the boiler plate of using it became a goal and voila OOP syntax was born.

Comment: @ElliottFrisch `has-a` relationship is only an implementation detail — the concept being implemented is inheritance. C allows upcasts from `Employee *` to `Person *` exactly to support implementing inheritance of this sort, and GObject (and other C OOP frameworks) make use of that. You seem to be arguing that the C OOP frameworks are somehow not doing real inheritance because *implement* it with aggregation, but that is conflating the interface and the implementation. It's like saying that git is not a versioned filesystem because it doesn't implement a kernel-level filesystem.

Answer (score 1):

Such a cast is undefined behavior in standard C, although it will work with many compilers.

Even if it works on a compiler you are currently using, be aware that it might break in a future version of the compiler, or with a different compiler. The C standard allows the compiler to assume that pointers to different types don't point to the same memory - except for some well-documented exceptions, which include cast of `LiteraryCharacter *` to `Person *`. The code that casts `LiteraryCharacter *` to `Employee *` can and will break under a compiler that makes use of this assumption to generate efficient code.

It might be a good idea to explain why you think you need this cast in the first place. Its equivalent would be quite incorrect in C++, and generate a `ClassCastException` in Java. After all, `LiteraryCharacter` doesn't have the fields of `Person`, such as `job`.

Answer (score 0):

That would be *undefined behaviour*. There is no such thing as inheritance in C.

You *might* get away with it if the structures had *exactly* the same layout but that would be very brittle code indeed.

Answer (score 0):

### Undefined behavior:

In your example you are casting to-from incompatible **types** which doesn't even compile because of the differences in the sizes of those two types. You can however cast to-from compatible (or even incompatible) **pointer types** and it will compile.

Casting to-from incompatible (or rather pseudo-compatible) types is undefined behavior, on some structures and compiler implementations it will work on others it won't.

Casting to **compatible** -- **pointer** types is safe as long as the compiler is taking care of the object structure / internal alignments / memory layout, etc. (there's an example below).

The "OK" part is debatable. Will it work? Yes because they have the same "in memory" layout and you are aware of that particular fact. But what happens when another programmer created that structure? You have to read its source to assess if it can be safely cast to another type.

### Encapsulation and future proofing:

Also most encapsulation techniques will only expose an "opaque type" which you can use via pointers -- pass it along to functions implemented within the same library/package and they do all of the structure specific work. In the case of "opaque types" you only know that that structure exists, you don't know it's internal structure so you can't just change the pointer type you're using to access it because you can't be sure of the structure compatibility behind it.

The point of encapsulation is to allow modules to be developed individually. So when the original developer of this external module changes the structure in a future version it breaks compatibility with your code (which shouldn't be using it that way anyway).

### Safer way to do this:

This is a non standard (yet pretty much ubiquitous) compiler feature of GCC.

```
typedef struct {
    char name[NAMESIZE];
    char sex;
} Person;

typedef struct {
    Person;
    char job[JOBSIZE];
} Employee;

typedef struct {
    Employee;
    char booktitle[TITLESIZE];
} LiteraryEmployeeCharacter;

LiteraryEmployeeCharacter* lec = malloc(sizeof(LiteraryEmployeeCharacter));
lec->name = "My character";
lec->sex = 'F';
lec->job = "Steward";
lec->booktitle = "A book";
```

By using unnamed fields you get access to `name`, `sex` and `job` as if they were defined in the `LiteraryEmployeeCharacter` structure.

By casting to a compatible pointer type the compiler knows the exact structure and position of every field and ca easily handle the structure correctly.

Comment: Have you tried this? What you call unnamed fields don't appear to have any effect in my version of gcc, and in fact produce a warning: `warning: declaration does not declare anything`

Comment: Of course I've tried it. Both anonymous structures as well as unnamed fields work just fine if you compile using the C11 standard (`gcc -std=c1x`).

Comment: If you want to use the c99 standard you'll have to enable some of GCCs  [C language extensions](http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc-3.1/gcc/C-Extensions.html#C%20Extensions) to do this. Such as: `gcc -std=c99 -fms-extensions fplan9-extensions`.

Comment: Anonymous structures are indeed part of C11, but they don't appear to work in the example you posted. On gcc 4.8.2, even with `-std=c1x` I get the warning, and the declaration is effectively no-op. `-fms-extensions` is used to "Accept some non-standard constructs used in Microsoft header files", definitely not standard C.

Comment: Many frequently used features that were not standard C eventually made it into C11 because of their ubiquitous status. I may be wrong about unnamed fields being standard C11, but C11 does have anonymous structs/unions which is an even more complex feature (at the syntactic level). Anonymous structs/unions more or less supersedes unnamed fields in just about every aspect.

Comment: If the code in your answer relies on non-standard features of your compiler, be upfront about it. The OP was clearly inquiring about standard (*pure*) C.

Comment: I agree, if it's non standard it should be mentioned (I wasn't aware of it not being standard, I assumed it was `c11` compliant -- but now I've mentioned the fact in my answer). OTOH, OP didn't tag the question with `ansi-c`, `c99` or `c11`, how come it's so clear to you that the inquiry is about standard (*pure*) C?

Comment: "Pure" is quoted from the OP; the question begins with "when doing inheritance in pure C...".